# Is there a way in Vega lite to use different color encodings on a choropleth map, the map has a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, vega-lite

As stated the map has a drop down menu that changes the display of the map, it selects different columns in the dataset. Ideally I would like to show a different "scheme" for input **one** and input **two** or what would also work in my case is to use "reverse" the "scale" encoding to reverse the color scheme for one of the two data columns being loaded

Code extract:

```
    {"$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",


  "config": {
    "background":"white",
    "view": {"stroke": "trasparent"}},
  
  "width": 700,
  "height": 500,
  
  "data": {
    "url": "https://unpkg.com/world-atlas@1.1.4/world/110m.json",
        "format": {
          "type": "topojson",
          "feature": "countries"}
      },

  "projection": {
    "type": "naturalEarth2"},
  
  "mark": {
      "type": "geoshape",
      "stroke": "rgb(50, 50, 50)",
      "strokeWidth":0.3},

    "transform": [
      {"calculate":"parseInt(datum.id)", "as":"id_N"},
            {
    "lookup": "id_N",
    "from": {
          "key": "id",
          "fields": ["alpha3", "name"],
          "data": {"url": "data1"}}
          },
      
        {"lookup": "alpha3",

        "from":{
          "data":{
            "url":"data2"},
            "key": "ISO3",
            "fields":["Vulnerability", "Gain"]
        }
        },        
        {"calculate": "datum.Vulnerability", "as": "Climate Vulnerability"},
        {"calculate": "datum.Gain", "as": "Overall Vulnerability Index"},
        {"calculate": "datum[Select]","as": "varSelected"},

      ],    

    "params": [
      {"name": "Select",
        "value": "Vulnerability",
        "bind": {
          "input": "select",
          "options": [
            "Climate Vulnerability",
            "Overall Vulnerability Index"]}}],
  
  
  "encoding": {

    "color":{
      "field":"varSelected",
      "type":"quantitative",
      "title": null,
      "scale":{
        "scheme": {"name": "turbo", "count":5}
        }
          },

        "tooltip":[
        {"field":"name", "title":"Country"},
        {"field":"varSelected","title":"Score","type":"quantitative"}],

  }
```

Comment: Please paste a full spec and desired outcome

Comment: The spec is full of errors and doesn't render. Please provide a basic *working* spec and the desired enhancement you want to make.